# Can PowerBI import Newline Delimited JSON?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to load [Newline Delimited](http://ndjson.org/) JSON in Power BI?

In this JSON format, each line is valid JSON.

When I try to import such data into Power BI, I get an error:

```
We encountered an error while trying to connect.

Details: "We found extra characters at the end of JSON input."
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in connector, however it should be possible to code it.

A naive example:

```
let
    Source =
        "{""OrderID"":1,""CustomerID"":1234,""Item"":""ITM-0001""}#(lf)" &
        "{""OrderID"":2,""CustomerID"":5678,""Item"":""ITM-0003""}",

    #"Newline Delimited" = Text.Split(Source, "#(lf)"),
    #"Each Parsed JSON" = List.Transform(#"Newline Delimited", Json.Document),
    #"Records To Table" = Table.FromRecords(#"Each Parsed JSON")
in
    #"Records To Table"
```

[image: Result]

When you get the data from file or Web, it is a binary, so first you may need to turn it into a text using `Text.FromBinary`.

Comment: What connector have you used here?

Comment: It could be any connector. Typically it’s Web.Contents if you get it from the web.